# Rotate Point Between Coordinate Systems

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have a point(s)

`P0(x,y,z)...Pn(x,y,z)`

and a plane described by two vectors and a normal.

`V1(x,y,z)`

`V2(x,y,z)`

`N1(x,y,z)`

I am rotating them so that they are axis aligned in the world by doing this

`P0'=(P0 DOT(V1),P0 DOT(V2), P0 DOT(N1))`

This works and the points are rotated as expected.  I want to know how to now rotate them, and new points back.  Basically the inverse operation

Thanks

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Do you know about inverse matrices?